# Insert Record based on flag

Tags: plsql

I have a table say tb_load_files.
It contains fields
file_name, file_date,file_loc,file_status

Now, File_status cane be x or y.
The requirement is there can be multiple records for x status for combination of 
(file_name, file_date,file_loc) but only one record for y status.

e.g.

```
file_name  file_date     file_loc  status
abc.txt     12-oct-07     NY         X
abc.txt     12-oct-07     NY         X
abc.txt     12-oct-07     NY         Y

abc.txt     12-oct-07     NY         Y    --  NOT ALLOWED
```

what could be the best way of designing these table?
   a. selecting data before insert
   b. trigger to check if value exists
or any other.
Please advice

Comment: Can you please clarify the requirements here?  Why is that final record 'not allowed'?  It sounds as if you are saying that any given Y record has to be unique, but X records do not have to be unique.  However, if that is true, then your example is confusing.

Comment: It is not clear why the last line is not allowed. The combination of file_name, file_date, and file_loc is the same as the first two rows, but they were ok? Perhaps a bit more explanation of what the "status" means would help.

Answer (score 1):

If there is going to be thousands of entries, I'd suggest that instead of wasting space by using multiple rows with the same data, add a column COUNT. The data can be then unique and can be better optimized with indexes if necessary.

Then, either create PL/SQL procedure callable by client, or (if client expects to work with table) create a updatable view + INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE triggers. Code inside it will just increase COUNT on existing record when status is X, or throw error if status is Y.

Comment: +1 Valid point on data duplication. @Avinash, you may want to consider adding the count as suggested by Juraj or may be splitting/normalizing your tables  to avoid duplication.

Comment: @Avinash, on what field is your table currently indexed ?